# How to display data based on current logged user?

Tags: c#

How do you display data that is retrieved from database according to the current login user? I know that I should declare the id, but I don't really know how...

I have 2 tables in SQL.

User:

ID || Name || Last_Name || date ||

List

ID || Product || description || user_id

```
private void BindGridView()
    {  
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConn"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                { 
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * From List where ID = @ID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ?);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        ad.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you working with WindowsForms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your table the `query` should be

```
select * from list where user_id = id
```

here `id` is the `userid` passed to the method

e.g `private void BindGridView(int id)`

another way is to use `session`

and to store id after login you have to store it in session

```
session["UserId"] = userid;
```

and you can use it in function like

```
int userid = Convert.ToInt32(session["UserId"]);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM list where user_id = " + userid + "";
```

and also dont forget to use `conn.Open()` and `conn.Close()` after executing query